# Set page size in mm's

Tags: paper-size

A contact has asked for a documents pages to be set to 130 x 198mm - and so my `\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{book}` isn't going to cut it - how do I specify page size in mm?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See page 6 of the `geometry` package [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperwidth=130mm,paperheight=198mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Damn, finally a question I am fully qualified to answer and someone gets to it first.

Answer (score 11):

Couldn't help but implement what came into my mind when I read the title of this question ... be mild on the downvotes, please :-)

[image: page size in MM's]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=9.98in,paperheight=19.94in,margin=0.05in]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\mm}[1]{\includegraphics[height=.1in,trim=1pt 5pt 1pt 3pt,clip]{mm#1}}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}%
\fontsize{.1in}{.1in}\selectfont%
\noindent\foreach \x in {1,2,...,65}{\mm1\mm2}\\
\foreach \x in {2,4,...,197}{\mm2\newline\mm1\newline}\mm2
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm gonna guess and say your measurements are wrong! (:-) If the 130mm should, as I believe, be 129mm, then here's how:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,mlargecrownvopaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```